Cannot find the CREDENTIAL<mainstorage path>because it doesn't exist or you don't have permission. Couldn't use view/function because of binding error
I migrate on premises database to ADLS via Azure data factory, Then I create Azure Synapse as a Data Warehouse to my newly transform data. When I connect it to power BI via Database SQL Authentication option (There are 3 option Windows, Database, Microsoft) it loaded the table in navigator but I can't read the data in table. It gives following error;

PS: Microsoft Login Works, but I want to login via Database Option.
In sql authentication I gave Synapse SQL admin username and Password and its endpoint.
I tried with giving blob contribute permission to my synapse workspace, but it didn't solve the issue.
How to solve this error?
